# Having problem with Nvidia Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia

So I am currently using 12.04 and have a GTX 580M, when I go to check the drivers it says that I dont have any proprietary drivers currently installed, so I am unable to download any newer ones (obviously.)

My problem is that I have been told that I will need to install the newest drivers in order for playonlinux etc. When I try and install the .run file direct from the Nvidia site it says that I need to close X Server first, however when I go into X Server it says

"You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.  Please edit your X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root), and restart the X server."

I have tried this in terminal and get this message

```
"Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".

VALIDATION ERROR: Data incomplete in file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.
                  Device section "Default Device" must have a Driver line.

Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as
'/etc/X11/xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original'
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'
```

Does anyone know how I can go about getting this to work?

EDIT: I have tried stopping X Server through terminal and all this does is close the GUI, it still wont allow me to apply the drivers

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here in this [blog post](http://dfourtheye.blogspot.in/2013/05/ubuntu-nvidia-driver-installation.html),

After executing `sudo nvidia-xconfig`, you need to enable additional drivers.

Execute `sudo software-properties-gtk` which will open up a window like this

[image]

Select the latest driver and then `reboot` your machine.